# Как поправить регулярное выражение?

Tags: php

нужно получить первую картинку в тексте поста ,но это выражение получает ,последнюю и при это под это выражение попадают `<iframe src="https://` которые идут после картинки ,но не первая картинка

```
preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match('/<img.+?src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*?>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
```